# How to compile jedit in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jedit

Can someone give steps for importing jedit in netbeans.  I followed the tutorial, in 
http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetbeansedJEdit#Converting_JEdit_into_a_Netbeans_Project not able to find, NetbeansedJEdit.zip in it.  when i try to open using netbeans by open project, i am not able to see the project icon.  Anything to do with build.xml file?

Comment: I have re-asked this question but in a far more thorough manner here, and will update the wiki linked in this question, if someone can answer how this works now:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693837/how-can-i-create-a-netbeans-7-3-project-wrapping-the-jedit-source-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as you suspected, the `build.xml` indicates *jedit* is a project compiled with ant. Follow [this example](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/freeform-import.html) (with jedit instead of pmd)

Comment: The linked wiki article is for netbeans 5.5, and is no longer workable information in netbeans 7.x.